# Changing css over if condition

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<div id="register_error">
    <?php
        echo "$error_msg";
    ?>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
if(document.getElementById("register_error").innerHTML)
{
    document.getElementById("signUpFormBackground").style.display = "block";
}
```

I want the JavaScript code to check every time the page loads if there is any text in the `#register_error` div, though my code doesn't seem to work, why is that? What am I missing? If any more information is needed just ask.

EDIT---------------------------------
I've cleared the whitespace as some of you said

```
<div id="register_error"><?php echo "$error_msg";?></div>
```

but it didn't helped, I think the problem is that this part of code never gets called,I haven't made it in function,I just wrote it in script tags. Also tried .trim() and .length() methods, but still same response.
EDIT2--------------------------------
I've made

```
enter code hereif(document.getElementById("register_error").innerHTML)
{
    document.getElementById("signUpFormBackground").style.display = "block";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("signUpFormBackground").style.display = "block";
}
```

and nothing happens,so I guess my problem is that I don't even get my code to start working,I always thought that if I put it in between script tags it'll always run at least once as web loads,so how do I actually run it on windows load,I've already tried this:

```
<script>
window.onload
{
    if (document.getElementById("register_error").innerHTML.length > 0 )
    {
        document.getElementById("signUpFormBackground").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("signUpFormBackground").style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

RESULT-----------------------------
Finally found my mistake,I didn't called the function and thought It'll do stuff without calling it, the code was fine.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? If your `<script>` tag appears **before** the HTML you posted above, then you'd get errors because the element wouldn't be in the DOM yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any amount of whitespace can throw off your `.innerHTML` check, and it looks like you have some already.  try this:

```
<div id="register_error"><?php echo "$error_msg";?></div>
```

Javascript:

```
if(document.getElementById("register_error").innerHTML == '')
{
    document.getElementById("signUpFormBackground").style.display = "block";
}
```

You can also check to see if `innerHTML.length > 0`:

```
if(document.getElementById("register_error").innerHTML.length > 0)
```

While not ideal, you can also move your error logic into your php:

```
<?php

if ($error_msg != '')
{
   echo "<style>#signUpFormBackground { display: block;}</style>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Or trim the innerHTML.

Comment: What does `var htmlString = document.getElementById('register_error').innerHTML; console.log(htmlString, htmlString.length, htmlString.trim().length)` output?

Answer (score 2):

You have your php code indented. Thus, the innerHTML has text even if there is nothing output from the PHP code. You should `trim()` your innerHTML before checking if it is empty

```
document.getElementById("register_error").innerHTML.trim()
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Eq6Ah/)

Comment: You might want to mention the compatibility/availability of [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is in the below `if` condition:

```
document.getElementById("register_error").innerHTML
```

Your inner html returns a string, so you must be checking its length as:

```
if(document.getElementById("register_error").innerHTML.length) {}
```

Comment: Testing `innerHTML.length` is equivalent to testing `innerHTML` since both evaluate to true if `innerHTML` is non-empty. The problem, however, is whitespace in the HTML causing `innerHTML` never to be completely empty.